# How should I draw UIBezierPaths that follow 3D points in a SCNSceneView?

Tags: 3d, uikit, scenekit, uibezierpath

Essentially I'm just trying to reimplement what's being shown in this video here: https://youtu.be/iw9MPZoPqCQ

In this video you'll see that they're somehow drawing lines connecting between 3D points but the lines themselves are 2D in nature, as they stay the exact same width on screen no matter how close or far they are from the camera.

My guess is they're projecting 3D points to 2D and creating UIBezierPath's from those 2D points. So I took this approach and it seemed to work fantastic! However there's one problem I can't find a great solution for: 3D points end up projected on to the 2D view regardless if they're in front or behind the camera!

After doing some research I came to find that this is a normal aspect of 3D graphics. The usual solution for this is to truncate any geometry that intersects the camera plane. Any points behind the plane can then be omitted, leaving you with only vertices that are in front of the camera plane to render while maintaining the same angles in every line.

This process is described well in the article here -  http://metalbyexample.com/up-and-running-3/ - starting under the subheading "From View Space to Clip Space".

So I'm stuck now wondering if I should try to implement my own janky version of clipping (which sounds pretty daunting to a 3D rendering noob like myself) or if there's possibly some better approach that might require less code? An approach that can hopefully still leverage UIBezierPath's awesome rendering features.

Thanks for checking out my question guys. :)

Comment: Are you sure that these are 2D lines and not just small cylinders in the video? Because connecting two points with a cylinder is very easy to do in SceneKit

Comment: @orangenkopf yeah I think if you look closely it’s clear that these lines have absolutely no change in width from perspective projection as they should have if they’re actual geometry. They’re exactly what you want if you’re going to convey lines to the user regardless of their distance from the device.